# Is there a way to create a public page or a url in Wordpress via PHP that isn't shown automatically on site menu?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a plugin for Wordpress, this plugin must show a list of results in HTML in a public page, this page must have its own url.

I know how to create a page in Wordpress via PHP code and how to add a tag to use the plugin, but the page then would be added to the website menu and I need to keep it outside of the Wordpress menus.

I can't use register_rest_route because it would give me a Json response and I need an HTML response. If I alter headers via PHP Wordpress would show an error.

Is there a way to create a public page in a Wordpress site via PHP that isn't shown on website menu? Or can I create a URL that shows directly in HTML my plugin code result?

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe by using a virtual page? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9870/how-do-you-create-a-virtual-page-in-wordpress

Comment: Why aren't you using [Wordpress Menus](https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-add-navigation-menu-in-wordpress-beginners-guide/)?